# Lebesgue integrable function in rationals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$ 
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 & x\notin\mathbb{Q}\\
0 & x\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases} .
$
As is well known $f$ is not integrable in the Riemann sense. Is it Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: Yes, with $\int_{[0,1]} f \ d\mu = 1$ as the rationals have zero measure.

Comment: Should it be $\int f d\lambda = \lambda(\Bbb{Q} \cap [0,1]) = 1$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lambda\left([0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}\right)=0$ since $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is countable. So, $\lambda\left([0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}\right)=\lambda([0,1]) - \lambda\left([0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}\right) = 1.$ Hence $\int f d\lambda = 0 \cdot\lambda\left([0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}\right) + 1\cdot\lambda\left([0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}\right) = 1$.